# How to check a MariaDB syntax error (Error Code 1064)?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I've 2 simples stored procedures on a MariaDB 10, in order to clean automatically data from my tables.
The first one reads configuration items from a simple table and passes that data to the second one, that deletes physically the records.
During the test all worked fine, but now I get the error **"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1  0,052 sec"** and I don't know why.

The procedure is the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`10.135.15.%` PROCEDURE `clean_table_checker`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE TMP_TIME_AGO INT(11);
    DECLARE TMP_ID INT(11);
    DECLARE TMP_RETENTION_SECS INT(11);
    DECLARE TMP_DBNAME VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE TMP_TABLENAME VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE TMP_TS_FIELD VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE TMP_LASTUPDATE INT(11);
    DECLARE TMP_RETENTION INT(4);
    DECLARE DONE INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE get_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT `id`, `dbname`, `tablename`, `ts_field`, `lastupdate`, `retention` FROM management.clean_table;    

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
        
    OPEN get_tables;
    
    loop_cursor_ptr: LOOP
        IF DONE THEN
            LEAVE loop_cursor_ptr;
        END IF;

        FETCH get_tables INTO TMP_ID, TMP_DBNAME, TMP_TABLENAME, TMP_TS_FIELD, TMP_LASTUPDATE, TMP_RETENTION;
        SET TMP_TIME_AGO = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - TMP_LASTUPDATE;
        SET TMP_RETENTION_SECS = TMP_RETENTION * 86400;

        IF TMP_LASTUPDATE is NULL THEN
            SET @SQL = CONCAT('UPDATE management.clean_table SET `lastupdate`=',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),' WHERE `id`=',TMP_ID,';');
        ELSEIF (TMP_TIME_AGO > TMP_RETENTION_SECS) THEN
            CALL clean_table_proc(TMP_DBNAME, TMP_TABLENAME, TMP_TS_FIELD, TMP_RETENTION_SECS);
            SET @SQL = CONCAT('UPDATE management.clean_table SET `lastupdate`=',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),' WHERE `id`=',TMP_ID,';');
        END IF;
        PREPARE STMT FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE STMT;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;


    END LOOP loop_cursor_ptr;

    CLOSE get_tables;
END
```

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Always tag SQL questions with `sql` as well as the specific DBMS; that will ensure they reach the largest number of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If neither of your conditions (`TMP_LASTUPDATE is NULL`, `TMP_TIME_AGO > TMP_RETENTION_SECS`) is true, the value of `@SQL` is not set and hence `NULL`. You are then trying to prepare a statement from a `NULL` value, which is why you are seeing the error that you are. You need to add a test as to whether execution of a query is necessary, for example:

```sql
SET @SQL = ''
IF TMP_LASTUPDATE is NULL THEN
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('UPDATE management.clean_table SET `lastupdate`=',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),' WHERE `id`=',TMP_ID,';');
ELSEIF (TMP_TIME_AGO > TMP_RETENTION_SECS) THEN
    CALL clean_table_proc(TMP_DBNAME, TMP_TABLENAME, TMP_TS_FIELD, TMP_RETENTION_SECS);
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('UPDATE management.clean_table SET `lastupdate`=',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),' WHERE `id`=',TMP_ID,';');
END IF;
IF @SQL != '' THEN
    PREPARE STMT FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE STMT;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
END IF;
```